# Can you transition a display property? If not, what's the best solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to do a transition on a list item:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li class="resume"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Resumé</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> Bio</a></li>
   <li id="backtoprojects" class="is-hidden"><a href="#" data-type="projectDie" ><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Back to Projects</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#backtoprojects').removeClass('is-hidden');

// hide back-to-projects-button on click of "backtoproject"
$('#backtoprojects a').on('click', function(){
   hasher.setHash();
   $('#backtoprojects').addClass('is-hidden');
});
$('[data-type="projectDie"]').click(function() {

        $('body').removeClass('projectLoaded');

        return false;

    })
```

;

**CSS**

```
.navbar ul li.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

So right off the bat the "Back to Projects" is hidden, it appears when a project is clicked on, and if you click on "Back to Projects" again it hides itself. I tried swapping `display:none` for opacity or visibility but you can still see the spacing as if "Back to Projects" was still there. I envisioned the "Back to Projects" link to slide in from the right as the entire `<ul>` is `float: right`.

Comment: instead of applying a class, why not use a built in jquery method like .hide() or .fadeOut()? It does the same exact thing

Comment: Or use css3 transitions ... toggle a class and let the css do what you need

Comment: No...you cannot transition the `display` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#backtoprojects').hide();
$('a').on('click', function(){
    $('#backtoprojects').show('slow');
});
$('#backtoprojects').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide('slow');
});
```

Full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/hdbj2rec/1/

Or you can use CSS to hide `#backtoprojects` initially.